# formats that a file handling C program can read from

Tags: c, file-io

I made a .txt and .dat file and wrote a program to read text from it but something strange happened it happens to read from both the files irrespective of the extension. What all extensions C program can read from other than .txt, .dat, .bin? Why such behavior?

Comment: The image posted in this question is unhelpful.  The relevant information it contains is *plain text* - you could just copy and paste it *as text*.  In the case where you do need to post a screenshot (this is not one of them), you know that Alt+PrntScr will capture just the active window rather then your entire desktop?

Comment: You should put the code in question formatted as code, not as screenshot. Also, it appears you have two versions of your program, but you only display image of source code for one version (well, part of it, part is hidden by that console window).

Comment: deleted the image is it fine now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C program can read from any file irregardless of it's extension.

Extensions don't actually do anything. You can put any extension you like on text file, it will still just be a text file. The same goes for other types of encodings. The difference comes when the operating system tries to figure out what program to open it with. If you rename a `.jpg` file `.txt` and open it, it will likely open in a text editor rather than in a picture viewer. Picture viewers should still be able to open it though, as it will still contain its original data.

**Edit:** Since you seem to be interested in reading text from files vs. reading data from files, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm) is some documentation for File IO in C.

`fgets` and `fputs` are there to read and write textual data:

```
char *fgets( char *buf, int n, FILE *fp );
int fputs( const char *s, FILE *fp );
```

`fread` and `fwrite` are there to read and write binary data:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size_of_elements, 
         size_t number_of_elements, FILE *a_file);
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size_of_elements, 
         size_t number_of_elements, FILE *a_file);
```

**Be careful!!** As stated by Clifford below:

> `fread()` will still translate line-ends if the file [was] not opened as binary. For a truly binary data format, this may break your code in ways that are possibly hard to spot.

`fgetc` and `fputc` are there to read binary data one byte at a time:

```
int fgetc( FILE * fp );
int fputc( int c, FILE *fp );
```

Comment: Ohh does it happen to read only text or it can read data as well ?

Comment: You can read in binary data (data not formatted as text) if you want to.

Comment: But obviously a function such as `fgets` is *meant* to read text, and not binary data.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not super familiar with file handling in C (I haven't done it in ages), but I'm fairly certain there must be functions for getting "raw" binary data from a `FILE *`.

Comment: Ahh, apparently `fread` will work with binary IO.

Comment: Of course there are: `fgetc`, `fread`. Functions such as `fgets` and `fscanf` assume the file is a text file, and handle a couple of binary characters in a special way, such as an `\n` as "end of line".

Comment: @anthropomorphic : Be careful, `fread()` will still translate line-ends if the file were not opened as binary.  For a truly binary data format, this may break your code in ways that are possibly hard to spot.

Answer (score 2):

File format is a matter of interpretation by your application code, it is not imposed by file extensions - that is just a naming convention - no more. The file name extension has no effect on file I/O - it is just part of the name.  The file name extension does not even effect the format of the content - a .dat file could just as easily contain plain text (for example .xml and .html are both plain text data file types).

The only distinction made between text and binary files by stdio is when opened as a text file, platform dependent line-end translation *may* occur.

On Windows this means that on input a *carriage-return + Line-feed* (CR+LF) sequence will be replaced with a single `'\n'` character (`'\n'` is in fact a linefeed), and on output every `'\n'` will be translated to CR+LF.  On Linux on the other hand, there is no distinction because Linux/Unix line-end convention is a single LF in any case.  This potential translation makes some usages of `fseek()` on a file opened as text complicated and non-portable.

To open a file as "binary" (i.e. no line-end translation), append a `b` to the *mode* argument string, e.g:

```
fp = fopen( "file.dat", "rb" ) ;
```

Note that there are legitimate reasons for opening a text file in binary mode, but you have to be aware that the CR+LF sequences will be read in intact (CR is represented by the escape sequence character constant `'\r'` in C).